# is it possible to get anchor visited state from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. i'm using jquery. i have a anchor list. i'm enumerate anchors, if it visited, set display:none;
2. i need when click on the anchor, anchor will changed to visited state from javascript?

How can i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, see [here](http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2006/08/i-know-where-youve-been.html) for an example. It uses `getComputedStyle` to find out if a link has been visited. There's also a variant of this hack that [doesn't require scripting](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070228/steal-browser-history-without-javascript/).

The relevant part of the example is this (modified for clarity):

```
a:visited {
    color: #00f;
}

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'http://example.com/';
document.body.appendChild(link);
var color = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(link, null).getPropertyValue('color');       
// check for visited
if (color == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") {           
    alert(link.href + ' has been visited');
}
```

May I ask what do you need it for?

Edit: WRT #2, you could open the link in an `iframe`. That would mark it as visited in the browser history. Like so:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**Edit**: You can create new CSS rules with JS. There's a [jQuery plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html) to make it more simple. Basically, you would do it like this:

```
$.rule('a:visited { color: #f06 !important }').appendTo('style');
```

Comment: i'm hacking some client generated html. this anchor code is not mine.

Comment: Thank you. This is good idea for checking any link already visited on client browser. But my problem is all state color is same.I'm trying to override anchor css style, but color shown previously. My most of goal is change anchor visited state style.

Comment: To anyone wondering why one would want to do such a thing. This can be use to "sniff" at a users history. For instance you have a huge list of 10k links each paired with a topic: 'technology', 'food', 'traveling', etc. You now know what ads to show the user since you now know what he or she likes. In a more serious note when you get access to ones password you can check what websites he also uses and try logging into them. More about it here: http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/PAPERS/2011/paper010.pdf

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it through CSS?

```
a:visited {display:none;}
```

Comment: By security reasons this is no more available. `For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke.` Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Avisited