# Getting browser history with Javascript?

Tags: css, browser-history, sniffing

This question has been asked many times but most of those questions are old.

I have tried several different techniques:

```
a:visited {} /* read computed style - always returns :link color*/
a:visited {} /* set height and measure that, turns out you can only set various colors */
a:link:after { content:"abc"} /* tried various styles */
/* the same restrictions apply when dealing with nested/child elements */
```

I've tried taking a "screenshot" of the div and putting it into the canvas in order to get pixel colors that way.

I've considered hovering a translucent div over an anchor and somehow using that to measure the color.

I've tried loading a stylesheet from a site you want to sniff and timing how long it takes (on first/second/... load) but the results are weird (sometimes it loads faster the first time like its actually faster over the network than locally cached or something).

```
<script>
    var t = new Date().getTime();
</script>
<link id="test" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://l.yimg.com/zz/combo?nn/lib/metro/g/breakingnews/breakingnews_0.0.49.css" />
<script> 
    document.getElementById("test").onload = function () {              var ft = ((new Date().getTime()) - t) + "ms";
        alert(ft);
    };
</script>
```

Mozilla outlines the why and hows of these security restrictions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector).

Is history sniffing completely impossible and if so are there any standard/accepted/user-friendly ways of doing it?

Comment: A user-friendly browser privacy exploit?

Comment: The user friendly solution would have to be legit. But an exploit solution could be anything.

Comment: Couldn't you (1) Create an hidden test div with for ex id="mytest" and put it in your html DOM, (2) create a new css "#mytest a:visited { ... }", (3) create a new "a" DOM element, (4) set its href to the URL of the site you want to snif, (5) append it to the div, (6)then test its style to know if it has been visited or not ? I found that way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584850/is-it-possible-to-get-anchor-visited-state-from-javascript

Comment: My bad, it seems its not more possible: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: With any luck, the browser developers are watching this site. If you figure out a way around their restrictions, hopefully they'll close that hole.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments highlight, you won't be able to obtain browser history information - at least, not if browsers are designed as they should - because it's a privacy violation.

There are some limited options:

- The `history` object has `back`, `forward` and `length` methods for
  navigating back and forwards in the current window or frame; but (privacy
  again) it is readable, so you cannot do things like
  `x = window.history[0]`
- Using cookies (or sessions) you could maintain navigation history *on your site*, and rely on that information for user-friendly features, limited to the site that you read cookies/session data on.
- We could imagine a multisite version by having every link redirected via a central site first, which would record history, and that site hosting a javascript library that provides features for visited links. It still relies on every link redirected through a central place for history keeping: so it's only applicable to sites that consent to that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @boisvert, it's a privacy violation. It was once possible but not on recent browser versions. It's probably better to try saving clicked links on localStorage and check that later. It's not 100% effective but with javascript on the browser side you're never 100%.

As a site node, alternatively you might want to do it server side. That would be 100% effective.