# Style the parent element of an anchor tag if it's visited

Tags: javascript, html, css, inheritance, styling

I've been using HTML for a long time and never really had to do/tried something like this. I have an *anchor tag* inside a *paragraph tag*, like so:

`<p>Hello <a href="path/page.html">World</a></p>`

I was wondering if there is a way to change the style the `p` element if `a` has already been visited, using nothing but CSS. I know *JavaScript* can do this and by any means feel free to post a *Vanilla JS* answer if you will for reference, but my question really is about how to do it using just CSS.

Since I predict someone will say something like **"Is the parent tag really necessary?"**, I know *HTML5* and *CSS3* brought whole new ways to style and manipulate content without the need for extra tags, but that's not the point of the question. The point is of how to do it if one ever needs to *(and in my case, I do)*.

Comment: There is no `parent` or `has` selector in CSS, so nope, you can't do that.

Comment: There is currently no parent selector. However it's worth noting that  [CSS4 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) provides a syntax for defining the "subject" of a selector by using an `!` exclamation sign. As `!p > a:visited {...}`, But this is not implemented in any web browsers yet.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. If anyone is still willing to post a JavaScript answer please go ahead, preferably without *jQuery* or other frameworks.

Comment: Updated using native JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues at play here.

1. You can't do this with pure CSS because currently their is no parent selector. As Hashem noted above, [it is currently included in the working draft for CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject).
2. [Questions such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584850/is-it-possible-to-get-anchor-visited-state-from-javascript) suggest that it might be possible using JavaScript, to check the colour of the link for example, and deduce from that, that the link is visited. However, I've just tried on Firefox 27, and it no longer works for me. I'd speculate that it's seen as a security issue, seeing as you could potentially exploit it to work out a user's particular internet history.

Initially I suggested looking at using the `::before` selector to try to achieve something, but after a little digging I came across [this article](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy) [(and this answer from SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839127/firefox-4-not-rendering-avisitedbefore-except-color) which might make for an interested read.

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/tXSPh/1/) (***updated*** to native JS) for my workings. It's worth noting I did try the native JavaScript check as mentioned in the above answer, as well as using the `:visited` selector in jQuery, but neither worked.

**JS**

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i ++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    console.log(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(anchor, null).getPropertyValue('color'));       
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://nowayjose.com">Never visited</a>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
a { color: #00FF00; }
a:visited { color: #FF0000; }
```

The potential security implications of how the `!` selector in CSS4 would play out with `:visited` rules are pretty interesting, given that you could style a different element and then potentially query that element for a style.

Comment: Thanks Hashem - see my final paragraph I just added, really interesting as to what they'll do.

Comment: Ian, that's very interesting, I hadn’t thought of it before.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer, totally forgot I had posted this question. Very thorough, thanks.

Comment: @LuizBerti no worries, thanks for coming back to it.