# css animation on unvisited links

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I can apply css color to unvisited links, but I seem unable to do so for css animations, at least in Firefox and Chrome.  Am I doing something wrong or is this a browser limitation?  In the example below, visited and unvisited links are animated.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8F9U/92/

```
@keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background: #38c;
    }
    10% {
        background: none;
    }
}
a:link {
    color: red;
    animation: highlight 4s infinite;
}
```

EDIT: based on Mr Lister's comment, I tried setting the color only and putting the animation in the parent.  Works for color, but not background-color (Firefox 31): http://jsfiddle.net/n8F9U/95/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The code you have (in your fiddle) will cause all links to flash blue every 4 seconds. You might be better off using CSS3 transitions, depending on your end goal.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to find out with Javascript whether the user has visited the link? That is considered a security risk (it allows websites to find out about the browsing habits of their users) and is not allowed. See [this blog](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/)

Comment: @BrandonGano yes it does.  I only want to flash unvisited links.

Comment: @MrLister no, there is no javascript involved.  I don't care to know if the user has visited the link.  I only want to encourage them to visit the unvisited link.

Comment: @Jayen You missed the important part of the blog. It says, _"we’re limiting what types of styling can be done to visited links to differentiate them from unvisited links._ ___Visited links can only be different in color:___ _foreground, background, outline, border, SVG stroke and fill colors"_ (emphasis mine). In other words, to answer your question, yes this is a browser limitation. As a consolation prize, I upvoted your question.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah I totally missed that part.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW if this was possible it would be a privacy issue. Animations are generating JS events (e.g. `animationstart`). By catching these events, websites would be able to sniff user's browsing history. Something similar to this incident: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/ .

Comment: @Jayen given related post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584850/is-it-possible-to-get-anchor-visited-state-from-javascript

Comment: @prakashstar42 I don't care about the javascript.  I want a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `background-color` to work, but you can do this with `border-color` and `color`:

http://jsfiddle.net/n8F9U/97/

```
@keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        color: #38c;
    }
    10% {
        color: red;
    }
    100% {
        color: red;
    }
}
a:visited {
    color: green;
    border-style: solid;
}
a:link {
    color: inherit;
    border-style: solid;
}
.wrapper {
    animation: highlight 4s infinite;
}
```